# How to put iPhone 3G into DFU mode when power button doesn't work

Tags: windows, iphone

I'm trying to enter DFU mode in my Iphone 3G. And yes, i know how to get it into DFU, but the problem is that my power button doesn't work, so my question is, is there a way to get in to DFU mode through the computer?

Comment: Did you try RecBoot ? http://jaxov.com/2010/05/recboot-iphone-recovery-mode/

Answer (score 1):

iClarified has provided [this post](http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=23009) that might be of use to you. It explains how to put your iPhone in DFU mode without using the power or home button.

Whatever you mean to do, just be sure to read the post completely before doing so, as without a power button you won't be able to shutdown your iPhone to reboot it again. Unless you let it go completely flat - this would take a while.

Answer (score 0):

Try using TinyUmbrella from this link blog.firmwareumbrella.com

Answer (score 0):

Please do as the followings: 
Open iTunes and connect the iPhone to your Mac. ... 
Press and hold the Home button and the Sleep/Wake button at the same time. ... 
After exactly 10 seconds release the Sleep/Wake button. Continue holding the home button until you iTunes pops up a message telling you that it has detected an iPhone in recovery mode.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is a bit complicated. Actually, we put iPhone into DFU mode via operating the  home button and power button.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.